# Advection and Decay PDE Confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$u_t+cu_x=-{\lambda}u : x, t > 0, u(x, 0) = 0 \forall x \in \Re$ and $u(0, t) = g(t) \forall t > 0$

I am confused on a particular step for $x<ct$.

For $x<ct$:

$e^{-\lambda{t}}\phi(0-ct)=g(t)$, so $\phi(-ct)=g(t)e^{-\lambda{t}}$.

We let $s=-ct$, so $\phi(s) = g(\dfrac{-s}{c})e^{\lambda{\dfrac{s}{c}}}$.

This is where I am confused. My professor said by an algebraic trick with $s$, we can replace s with $x-ct$ and get the solution:

$u(x, t)=e^{-\lambda{t}}e^{-\lambda(\dfrac{x-ct}{c})}g(-\dfrac{x-ct}{c})=e^{-\lambda\dfrac{x}{c}}g(-\dfrac{x-ct}{c})$

Hopefully I typed the solution correctly. Let me know if I messed up or missed any negative signs.

What is the algebraic trick? I did ask my professor, but he seemed frustrated with why I didn't know what the trick was.

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow a slightly different approach when solving linear first order PDE's. So this may look a bit more involved to you. Skip to 'Summarizing' to see a somewhat more concise explanation of what I think was going on in your professor steps.

To solve this kind of equation I find extremely useful to use the change of variable $w(x,t)=e^{\lambda t} u(x,t)$. It is easy to verify that $w(x,t)$ satisfies

$$
w_t+cw_x=0,\quad w(x,0)=0,\quad w(0,t)=e^{-\lambda t}g(t).
$$

Now, this is the simple transport equation, and the solution for $w$ is constant along the characteristics $x-ct=s$, so you can travel back on the characteristics until you hit either the initial or the boundary condition. If $x<ct$, then you'll hit the boundary condition. Therefore,

$$
w(x,t)=w(0,t_0)
$$
where $t_0$ is the point where the characteristic hits the boundary condition, and depends on both $x$ and $t$. Its value is easily computed:

$$
x-ct=s \Rightarrow 0-ct_0 = s = x-ct\Rightarrow t_0 -\frac{x-ct}{c}.
$$

Therefore, for $x<ct$, we have $w(x,t)=w(0,t_0)=e^{-\lambda \frac{ct-x}{c}}g\left(\frac{ct-x}{c}\right)$. Finally, you can roll back to the original unknown $u$ by multiplying by $e^{\lambda t}$.

Summarizing: I think your professor used a somewhat confusing notation. The first equation containing $\phi$ looked somewhat "given from above". Yes, $w$ is constant on lines of the form $x-ct$, and he basically called $\phi(x-ct)=w(x,t)$. But then from there he took it to a somewhat mystic route, hard to follow. In particular, when he writes $0-ct$, that $t$ is not a variable anymore, but it is the time at which the characteristic $x-ct$ hits the $t$-axis (what I called $t_0$). Letting $s=-ct$ is misleading then, cause it's actually $s=-ct_0$. The starting point should always be $s=x-ct$, with $s$ constant along the characteristic (the general equation of a characteristic), and when you're on the $t$-axis, then $x=0$ and $t=t_0$, leaving you with $s=-ct_0$. Then you can say

$$
e^{-\lambda t_0} \phi (-ct_0)=g(t_0)
$$
and since $s=x-ct$ is constant over the characteristic, then $s=-ct_0$, so you can write

$$
e^{-\lambda t_0} \phi (x-ct) = g(t_0).
$$
Then use $-ct_0=s=x-ct$ to solve for $t_0$ in terms of $x$ and $t$ to give a complete expression to the solution.